# Does Razor View @model initialize the model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a razor view which uses the @model keyword. I added a breakpoint in the model's constructor and whenever the view is rendered the breakpoint does not get called meaning it does not go into the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  @model only *declares* the model type.  If you need an instance of the model, then you must create one in your controller and pass it to the view, ie :

```
return View(new MyModel());
```

However, it's not always necessary to create an instance.  This is only necessary if you need to access instance properties, such as a list of items that you need to iterate over.